# How do I fix an "unresolved reference to Full-text Catalog" in a SQL Server Data Tools Project

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, dacpac

Using SQL Server Data Tools (12.0.50730.0) targeting Microsoft Azure SQL Database V12, I'm trying to deploy a database and set up full text indexing.

I've created the Catalog using SSMS as instructed here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187035(v=sql.105).aspx

```
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG MyCatalog
```

When I go into Visual Studio 2013 and add the full text indexes in my database project the following is added to my table definition and I fill out the table name, column, key and catalog:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON [MyTable] ([MyColumn]) KEY INDEX [MyKey] ON [MyCatalog] WITH CHANGE_TRACKING AUTO
```

When I do that I see an error that the Full-text Index contains an unresolved reference

```
SQL71501: Full-text Index on [MyTable] has an unresolved reference to Full-text Catalog [MyCatalog].
```

This makes sense to me because I had to create the Catalog outside Data Tools, but how do I move forward with creating the Full Text Index?

Answer (score 0):

I found one way to fix this,

1. When you create the Full Text catalog, specify that it's the default
   for the the database

   `CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG MyCatalog AS DEFAULT`
2. Remove `ON [MyCatalog]` from the line that creates the Full Text Index

   `CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON [MyTable] ([MyColumn]) KEY INDEX [MyKey] WITH CHANGE_TRACKING AUTO`